# React Native - Animation only works after Toggle Inspect on Android

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I'm quite new on React/React-Native environment and I'm facing some problems with Animations on Android.

I'm using a react animation to show a bottom Alert on errors and warnings.
The problem is that the animation is working fine on iOS but only works on Android after I enable the "Toggle Inspector", if I don't enable it the animation doesn't work, on debugger I'm able to see that the component is on the React components structure.

I already tried workarounds as setting the **Animated.Value** to ***0.01*** and changing **Animated.createAnimatedComponent** to ***Animated.View***.

The animation should occur after the state is changed and the **visible** property is set to ***TRUE***, the change of the state is OK as I can see it working on the React Native Debbuger, and the **slideIn/slideOut** functions are being called by the **useEffect** hook.

I'm on version ***React 16.11.0*** and ***React-Native 0.62.2***

**UPDATE**

I removed *position: absolute* from my component and now I'm able to see the animation on the top of my screen, I've tried to change the value of *z-index* to a higher value (I don't have any z-index higher than 1 in my app) but it didn't worked as well.

Here is the main part of the code:

```html
export const Alert = withTheme(({ theme: { primary, textGray } }) => {
  const translateValue = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const {
    visible,
    data: { type, message }
  } = useSelector(({ notification }) => notification);

  const slideIn = useCallback(() => {
    Animated.timing(translateValue, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 1000,
      useNativeDriver: true
    }).start();
  }, [translateValue]);

  const slideOut = useCallback(() => {
    Animated.timing(translateValue, {
      toValue: 0,
      duration: 1000,
      useNativeDriver: true
    }).start();
  }, [translateValue]);

  const handleClose = () => {
    dispatch(hideNotification());
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (visible) {
      slideIn();
    } else {
      slideOut();
    }
  }, [visible, slideIn, slideOut]);

  return (
    <Wrapper
      style={{
        transform: [
          {
            translateY: translateValue.interpolate({
              inputRange: [0, 1],
              outputRange: [300, 0]
            })
          }
        ]
      }}>
      <Content>
        <Icon name={icons[type]} size={20} color={primary} />
        <Message>{message}</Message>
      </Content>
      <Button
        onPress={handleClose}
        accessible
        accessibilityRole="button"
        accessibilityLabel="Fechar notificação">
        <Icon size={20} name="x" color={textGray} />
      </Button>
    </Wrapper>
  );
});

const Wrapper = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(styled.SafeAreaView`
  width: 100%;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-top-color: ${({ theme: { border } }) => border};
  background: ${({ theme: { background } }) => background};
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
`);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed!
It seems that there are some problems with ***z-index*** on Android.
To fix the problem I just added ***elevation: 1*** when the Platform is Android.

See the code below:

```js
    <Wrapper
          isAndroid={Platform.OS === 'android'}
          style={{
            transform: [
              {
                translateY: translateValue.interpolate({
                  inputRange: [0, 1],
                  outputRange: [300, 0]
                })
              }
            ]
          }}>
          <Content>
            <Icon name={icons[type]} size={20} color={primary} />
            <Message>{message}</Message>
          </Content>
          <Button
            onPress={handleClose}
            accessible
            accessibilityRole="button"
            accessibilityLabel="Fechar notificação">
            <Icon size={20} name="x" color={textGray} />
          </Button>
        </Wrapper>
      );

    const Wrapper = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(styled.SafeAreaView`
      width: 100%;
      border-top-width: 1px;
      border-top-color: ${({ theme: { border } }) => border};
      background: ${({ theme: { background } }) => background};
      z-index: 1;
      position: absolute;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      ${({ isAndroid }) => isAndroid && 'elevation: 1'}
    `);
```